# communicaton between central instance

Tags: volttron

I have a question about volttron.

I installed two volttron_central `instance(called VC_1, VC_2)`.

Also installed 3 volttron_sub `instance(called VS_1, VS_2, VS_3)`.

and then `VS_1` and `VS_2` connect to `VC_1` like this below picture.
[image]

Also, `VS_3` connect to `VC_2` like this below picture.
[image]

Actually, I want to connect between two `VOLTTRON_Central` instance but I don't 
know how.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is supported out of the box (at the present time) with volttron.  You can follow the same pattern as the ForwarderAgent to make connections between two different volttron instances, however.